# Copy random row from the sheets instead of defining a row every time in the parameters

Tags: vba, excel

This code in its current setting copies row 5 in all sheets to a master sheet. i need it to pull up a random row in a range.

```
Sub test()

    Dim curRow As Integer
    Dim activeWorksheet As Worksheet
    Set activeWorksheet = ActiveSheet
    curRow = 1
       For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Not ws.Name = activeWorksheet.Name Then
            ws.Range("5:6").Copy Destination:=activeWorksheet.Range(CStr(curRow) & ":" & CStr(curRow) + 1)

            curRow = curRow + 1
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```

I tried wring the random code like this but it failed with runtime error 1004

```
Sub test()

    Dim curRow As Integer
    Dim activeWorksheet As Worksheet
    Set activeWorksheet = ActiveSheet
    curRow = 1
    rndnum = Int((50 - 30 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Not ws.Name = activeWorksheet.Name Then
            ws.Range("(rndnum):(rndnum+1)").Copy Destination:=activeWorksheet.Range(CStr(curRow) & ":" & CStr(curRow) + 1)

            curRow = curRow + 1
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Put the variables out of the string in ws.Range

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use variables in Range, do it like this:

```
'if you only want to use Rows
Range(var1 & ":" & var2)
'if you want to refer to a cell
Range(Cells(varRow,varColumn))
```

Comment: i  just want it to pull up a random  number and copy that random one row


however whenever i try to assign a random number to a variable and use it it keep throwing this error up

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close. One of the row references was working (although the CStr conversion was unnecessary); the other was malformed.

```
Sub test()
    Dim curRow As Long, rndNum As Long, ws As Worksheet

    With ActiveSheet
        curRow = 1
        rndNum = Int((50 - 30 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
        For Each ws In .Parent.Worksheets
            If Not ws.Name = .Name Then
                ws.Range(rndNum & ":" & rndNum + 1).Copy _
                    Destination:=.Range(curRow & ":" & curRow + 1)
                curRow = curRow + 2
            End If
        Next ws
    End With

End Sub
```

I've also added a [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) to reduce the redundant calls to the var assigned to the [ActiveSheet property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx). The `ws` var should have been declared.

Comment: just to add that the copy/paste statement could be reduced to `ws.Rows(rndNum).Resize(2).Copy Destination:=.Rows(curRow)`. And that most probably `curRow` should be incremented by two, to avoid overwriting the 2nd row pasted in the previous iteration

Comment: Both good points; especially the catch on the increment. Thank you! (edit applied)